# Find an element in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, search, tuples

I have a list 'a'

```
a= [(1,2),(1,4),(3,5),(5,7)]
```

I need to find all the tuples for a particular number. say for 1 it will be

```
result = [(1,2),(1,4)]
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 316, accepted):

If you just want the first number to match you can do it like this:

```
[item for item in a if item[0] == 1]
```

If you are just searching for tuples with 1 in them:

```
[item for item in a if 1 in item]
```

Answer (score 175):

There is actually a clever way to do this that is useful for any list of tuples where the size of each tuple is 2: you can convert your list into a single dictionary.

For example,

```
test = [("hi", 1), ("there", 2)]
test = dict(test)
print test["hi"] # prints 1
```

Comment: How do you apply this to Bruce's problem?

Comment: Good answer (though possibly not for this question). Worked well for me to determine if a value was in a list of choice tuples (eg; if "hi" in test)

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question, as MagicLAMP suggests. Specifically, `dict(X)` converts X into a dictionary where the last tuple of any common first element, is the value that is used. In the example of the OP, this would return (1,4) as opposed to both (1,2) and (1,4).

Comment: This may not answer the question above, but this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 29):

Read up on [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
[ (x,y) for x, y in a if x  == 1 ]
```

Also read up up [generator functions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) and the `yield` statement.

```
def filter_value( someList, value ):
    for x, y in someList:
        if x == value :
            yield x,y

result= list( filter_value( a, 1 ) )
```

Comment: `if x == 1` should be `if x == value`

Answer (score 12):

```
[tup for tup in a if tup[0] == 1]
```

Answer (score 10):

```
for item in a:
   if 1 in item:
       print item
```

Answer (score 10):

The `filter` function can also provide an interesting solution:

```
result = list(filter(lambda x: x.count(1) > 0, a))
```

which searches the tuples in the list `a` for any occurrences of `1`. If the search is limited to the first element, the solution can be modified into:

```
result = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 1, a))
```

Answer (score 3):

Or `takewhile`, ( addition to this, example of more values is shown ):

```
>>> a= [(1,2),(1,4),(3,5),(5,7),(0,2)]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x[0]==1,a))
[(1, 2), (1, 4)]
>>>
```

if unsorted, like:

```
>>> a= [(1,2),(3,5),(1,4),(5,7)]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x[0]==1,sorted(a,key=lambda x: x[0]==1)))
[(1, 2), (1, 4)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using filter function:

```
>>> def get_values(iterables, key_to_find):

        return list(filter(lambda x:key_to_find in x, iterables)) 

>>> a = [(1,2),(1,4),(3,5),(5,7)]

>>> get_values(a, 1)

>>> [(1, 2), (1, 4)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [i for i in a if 1 in i]
```

[(1, 2), (1, 4)]

Comment: While correct, how is this different from `[item for item in a if 1 in item]` in the accepted answer posted 8 years earlier? Also note this will also match `(2, 1)` and `(4, 1)`.

Answer (score -3):

if you want to search tuple for any number which is present in tuple then you can use

```
a= [(1,2),(1,4),(3,5),(5,7)]
i=1
result=[]
for j in a:
    if i in j:
        result.append(j)

print(result)
```

You can also use `if i==j[0] or i==j[index]` if you want to search a number in particular index