# iterating quickly through list of tuples

Tags: python

I wonder whether there's a quicker and less time consuming way to iterate over a list of tuples, finding the right match. What I do is:

```
# this is a very long list.
my_list = [ (old1, new1), (old2, new2), (old3, new3), ... (oldN, newN)]

# go through entire list and look for match
for j in my_list:
    if j[0] == VALUE:
        PAIR_FOUND = True
        MATCHING_VALUE = j[1]
        break
```

this code can take quite some time to execute, depending on the number of items in the list. I'm sure there's a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming a bit more memory usage is not a problem and if the first item of your tuple is hashable, you can create a [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) out of your list of tuples and then looking up the value is as simple as looking up a key from the `dict`. Something like:

```
dct = dict(tuples)
val = dct.get(key) # None if item not found else the corresponding value
```

**EDIT**: To create a reverse mapping, use something like:

```
revDct = dict((val, key) for (key, val) in tuples)
```

Comment: that looks great but will only allow me to search by `old value`. do I need to create two dicts so that I can search in the new and old value fields?

Comment: @memyself: Yes, you are correct. If you need to search by *both* old and new values, you'll have to create two dicts. But I guess it's not that bad if all you want is fast look-ups. I have added the sample snippet for creating reverse dict.

Comment: I didn't know about get(), this has just made my life so much simpler.

Answer (score 82):

I think that you can use

```
for j,k in my_list:
  [ ... stuff ... ]
```

Comment: but that won't make the loop execute faster. will it?

Comment: You should check out this other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191699/find-an-element-in-a-list-of-tuples

Comment: found it easy to understand, tks

Answer (score 5):

The question is dead but still knowing one more way doesn't hurt:

```
my_list = [ (old1, new1), (old2, new2), (old3, new3), ... (oldN, newN)]

for first,*args in my_list:
    if first == Value:
        PAIR_FOUND = True
        MATCHING_VALUE = args
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

The code can be cleaned up, but if you are using a list to store your tuples, any such lookup will be O(N).

If lookup speed is important, you should use a `dict` to store your tuples. The key should be the 0th element of your tuples, since that's what you're searching on. You can easily create a dict from your list:

```
my_dict = dict(my_list)
```

Then, `(VALUE, my_dict[VALUE])` will give you your matching tuple (assuming `VALUE` exists).

Answer (score 1):

I wonder whether the below method is what you want.

You can use `defaultdict`.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> s = [('red',1), ('blue',2), ('red',3), ('blue',4), ('red',1), ('blue',4)]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in s:
       d[k].append(v)    
>>> sorted(d.items())
[('blue', [2, 4, 4]), ('red', [1, 3, 1])]
```