# Python: Given a list of integers x, write a single expression that returns True if all odd index values are twice their preceding values

Tags: python, list, zip, program-slicing

Given a list of integers, say,
x = [5, 10, 6, 12, 10, 20, 11, 22]
write a single expression that returns True if all odd index values
are twice their preceding values.
**We need to use skip slicing, zip, all, and list comprehension**

I'm new to Python programming (extensive experience in Java though). This is just a basic question on python syntax, but I'm not able to do it.
I tried the following:

`list(zip(x[::2], x[1::2]))`

this expression returns me a list like below
`[(5, 10), (6, 12), (10, 20), (11, 22)]`

After this I'm lost how to check the condition on the pairs. Looking for something like

`print(all([False for pair in list(zip(x[::2],x[1::2]))]) "write something in proper format that checks pair values for double condition")`

Comment: "We need to use ..." - this is for learning purposes I suppose?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/16021600/2823755](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16021600/2823755) ... [https://stackoverflow.com/a/10867891/2823755](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10867891/2823755)

Comment: Yes, this is for learning purpose. I know this is a very trivial question to ask on this forum, but coming from Java, Python has a lot more of these tricky syntaxes, and I was not able to crack it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using Zip, Slicing & List Comprehension**

```
x = [5, 10, 6, 12, 10, 20, 11, 22]
all([b == 2*a for a, b in zip(x[::2], x[1::2])])  # True
```

**Explanation**

Generator for number pairs

```
zip(x[::2], x[1::2]) # produces [(5, 10), (6, 12), (10, 20), (11, 22)]
```

Loop through the tuples (setting to a, b as we go)

```
for a, b in zip(x[::2], x[1::2])
```

Check condition

```
b == 2*a   # second number is twice 1st
```

Check if True everywhere

```
all(...)
```

Comment: Thanks [DarryIG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3066077/darrylg) for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

This?

```py
x = [5, 10, 6, 12, 10, 20, 11, 22]
result = all(x2 == 2*x1 for x1,x2 in zip(x[::2],x[1::2]))
print(result) # True
```

Comment: Your solution is on point. Thanks! However, your solution is iterating over a tuple, say I use this `list(zip(x[::2], x[1::2]))` so this will give me a list like `[(5, 10), (6, 12), (10, 20), (11, 22)]`. How do I do the same thing on list (which has these pairs)? What exactly is this called in Python ? A List of List ??

Comment: @inferno `'[(5, 10), (6, 12), (10, 20), (11, 22)]'` is called `str`. `[(5, 10), (6, 12), (10, 20), (11, 22)]` is called `list` (of `tuple`s (of (pair of) `int`s)), depending on how precise you want to be

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
In [123]: x
Out[123]: [5, 10, 6, 12, 10, 20, 11, 22]

In [124]: all([x[i]/x[i-1]==2 for i in range(1, len(x) - 1, 2)])
Out[124]: True
```

Comment: I need to use "skip slicing, zip, all, and list comprehension". Your solution does not contain the zip and list methods. Can you provide a solution using these.

Comment: `all([z/y==2 for y,z in [x for x in zip(x[::2],x[1::2])]])`

Comment: Yes! this looks more on point. Thanks everyone in the community for helping out :)

Comment: This is more accurate: `all([y/x==2 for x,y in zip(x[::2],x[1::2])])`