# How to get JJ and NN (adjective and Noun) from the triples generated StanfordDependencyParser with NLTK?

Tags: parsing, python-3.x, nltk, stanford-nlp, triples

i got triples using the following code, but i want to get nouns and adjective from tripples, i tried alot but failed, new to NLTK and python, any help ?

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser
dp_prsr= StanfordDependencyParser('C:\Python34\stanford-parser-full-2015-04-20\stanford-parser.jar','C:\Python34\stanford-parser-full-2015-04-20\stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar', model_path='edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz')
word=[]
s='bit is good university'
sentence = dp_prsr.raw_parse(s)
for line in sentence:
    print(list(line.triples()))
```

[(('university', 'NN'), 'nsubj', ('bit', 'NN')), (('university', 'NN'), 'cop', ('is', 'VBZ')), (('university', 'NN'), 'amod', ('good', 'JJ'))]

i want to get university and good and BIT and universityi tried the following but couldnt work.

```
   for line in sentence:
    if (list(line.triples)).__contains__()  == 'JJ':
       word.append(list(line.triples()))
   print(word)
```

but i get empty array... please any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Linguistically

What you're looking out for when you look for triplets that contains a `JJ` and an `NN` is usually a Noun phrase `NP` in a context-free grammar.

In dependency grammar, what you're looking for is a triplet that contains the the JJ and NN POS tags in the **arguments**. Most specifically, when you're for a constituent / branch that contains an adjectival modified Noun. From the `StanfordDepdencyParser` output, you need to look for the **predicate** `amod`. (If you're confused with what's explained above it is advisable to read up on Dependency grammar before proceeding, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar.

Note that the parser outputs the triplets, `(arg1, pred, arg2)`, where the argument 2 (`arg2`) depends on argument 1 (`arg1`) through the predicate (`pred`) relation; i.e. `arg1` governs `arg2` (see, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_(linguistics))

---

### Pythonically

Now to the code part of the answer. You want to iterate through a list of tuples (i.e. triplets) so the easiest solution is to specifically assign variables to the tuples as you iterate, then check for the conditions you need see [Find an element in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191699/find-an-element-in-a-list-of-tuples)

```
>>> x = [(('university', 'NN'), 'nsubj', ('bit', 'NN')), (('university', 'NN'), 'cop', ('is', 'VBZ')), (('university', 'NN'), 'amod', ('good', 'JJ'))]
>>> for arg1, pred, arg2 in x:
...     word1, pos1 = arg1
...     word2, pos2 = arg2
...     if pos1.startswith('NN') and pos2.startswith('JJ') and pred == 'amod':
...             print ((arg1, pred, arg2))
... 
(('university', 'NN'), 'amod', ('good', 'JJ'))
```

Comment: great (Y), this is what i wanted... it worked, but i saw this can be done by using Tregex,  will it be better to do it by tregex ? if yes, any code help for the above example ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly but I don't use Tregex, maybe asking another question for someone else to answer might get you better experts on that package =) If not, do post to https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_source=digest&utm_medium=email#!forum/nltk-users and see whether you get some help there.