# How to handle KeyError exceptions properly via try / except?

Tags: python, exception, assert

Edited for clarification: I'm trying to do a school exercise that requires me to build function that receives an element and a tuple and in case the element is in the tuple, it returns its positions in reverse i.e:

```
findInTupleA (1 , (1,2,3,1)
```

prints

```
[3, 0]
```

But in case the element doesn't exist in the tuple, a `KeyError` should be sent saying "element not in tuple".

```
def findInTupleA(elem,tuplo):
    lista_indices = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(tuplo):
        try:
            if tuplo[i] == elem:
                lista_indices.append(i)
            i = i + 1
        except KeyError:
            return "element not in tuple"

    if len(lista_indices)>=1:
        return lista_indices[::-1]
    else:
        return lista_indices
```

Still it's not working as intended, since if I give it element 1 and tuple (2,3) it returns a empty list instead of the key error, and while I'm asking, `reverse()` isn't working on the second `if`, no idea why.

P.S. If you'd like to comment on ways I could improve the code it would be awesome, same for an assert part!

Comment: Why? `ele in tuplo` isn't working?

Comment: please fix your code indentation.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. The program, as written, is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: What makes you think anything in this code would cause a KeyError for you to catch?

Comment: Why do you expect a `KeyError` actually ? Oh and yes: are you sure you really understood the exercice's description ? Aren't you supposed to _raise_ an exception in your function and catch it outside the function call instead ?

Comment: Sorry the copy paste was from a word and i didnt saw it. The exercise says that if there isn't any tuple with the element it should launch the exception (raise?) KeyError "element not in tuple"

Comment: What are you supposed to be returning if the tuple does contain the item? Your code seems like it's probably doing the wrong thing (checking for an exception instead of raising one itself), but it's not obvious what the right thing is supposed to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have misunderstood your assignment. I don't think you need to be using a `try` and `except` to catch an exception inside your function, but rather, you're supposed to be raising the exception yourself (and maybe using `try`/`except` outside the function to handle it).

Try something more like this, and see if it does what you need:

```
def findInTupleA(elem,tuplo):
    lista_indices = []    
    i = 0
    while i < len(tuplo):
        if tuplo[i] == elem:
            lista_indices.append(i)
        i = i + 1

    if len(lista_indices) >= 1:
        return lista_indices
    else:
        raise IndexError("element not in tuple")
```

Comment: This worked out, correct me if im wrong, we run the cycle normally then check if the output list is empty or not, if it is, it raises the exception?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what this code does. You could check for the element before the loop with `if elem in tuplo`, but the `in` operator does essentially the same thing as your explicit loop, so the separate check is a bit silly. I'm not sure `IndexError` is the most appropriate exception to raise in this situation (`ValueError` would be more natural), but you should match the specification you've been given for your assignment.

Answer (score 3):

How about checking if the element `index` is in the tuple. If the element doesn't exist then return `element not in tuple` on the exception `ValueError` like this:

```
def in_tuple(elem, tuplo):

    try:
        return tuplo.index(elem)
    except ValueError:
        return 'element not in tuple'

print in_tuple(1, (2, 3))
```

Comment: Was not what i was looking for but it's great information and works great, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue lies with indenting.  I think what you are aiming for is...

```
def findInTupleA(elem,tuplo):
    lista_indices = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(tuplo):
        try:
            if tuplo[i] == elem:
                lista_indices.append(i)
        except KeyError:
            return "element not in tuple"
        i = i + 1

    if len(lista_indices)>=1:
        return lista_indices[::-1]
    else:
        return lista_indices
```

Comment: when i run findInTupleA(1, (0,2,3,4)) it returns [] instead of the KeyError message

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191699/find-an-element-in-a-list-of-tuples