# Search for a char in list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists, and I want to return those sublists that have a specific char.

If the list is:

```
lst = [['a', 'e'], ['g', 'j'], ['m', 'n', 'w'], ['z']]
```

I want to retrive `['g', 'j']` "or it's position"  if I search using `j` or `g`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find an element in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191699/find-an-element-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:-**

```
lst = [['a', 'e'], ['g', 'j'], ['m', 'n', 'w'], ['z']]
def search(search_char):
    result = [x for x in lst if search_char in x]
    return result
print(search('g'))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start there is a keyword error in your variable - list is a keyword, try my_list.

This works for returning the list you want:

```
#Try this
my_list = [['a', 'e'], ['g', 'j'], ['m', 'n', 'w'], ['z']]
def check_for_letter(a_list,search):
    for i in a_list[:]:
        if search in a_list[0]:
            return a_list[0]
        else:
            a_list[0] = a_list[1]
```

Session below:

```
>>> check_for_letter(my_list,"j")
['g', 'j']
>>>
```

Comment: Comment if you want position of list as well or instead.

Comment: I've managed to do it manually, But i thought there is an efficient way to do it .    



P.S. I just used List to clarify my question, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is one way. It works even for repeats.

```
lst = [['a', 'e'], ['g', 'j'], ['m', 'n', 'w'], ['z']]

def searcher(lst, x):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if x in lst[i]:
            yield i

list(searcher(lst, 'g'))                        # [1]
list(map(lst.__getitem__, searcher(lst, 'g')))  # [['g', 'j']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [['a', 'e'], ['g', 'j'], ['m', 'n', 'w'], ['z']]

spec_char = input("What character do you want to find?: ")#ask for a character to find

def find_char(spec_char):
    for list_count, each_list in enumerate(lst):      #iterates through each list in lst
        if spec_char in each_list:                    #checks if specified character is in each_list
            return spec_char, lst[list_count]         #returns both the character and list that contains the character

def main():                                           #good habit for organisation
    print(find_char(spec_char))                       #print the returned value of find_char

if __name__ == '__main__':                            
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
lst = [['a', 'e'], ['g', 'j'], ['m', 'n', 'w'], ['z']]

def search(spec_char):
    for subList in lst:
        if spec_char in subList:
            return subList
    return False

print search('g')
>>> ['g', 'j']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y=[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f'],['f']]
result=[x for x in y if 'f' in x])
```

here I took 'f' as the character to be searched

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, we can also use the lambda and the filter functions.

The basics for lambda and filter function can be found in python documentation.

```
lst = [['a', 'e'], ['g', 'j'], ['m', 'n', 'w'], ['z']]
ch = input('Enter the character') # or directly type the character in '' 

# lambda <parameter to the function>: <value to be returned>
# filter(<lambda function to check for the condition>, <sequence to iterate over>)

r = list(filter(lambda lst: ch in lst,lst))
print(r)
```

Note: To see the value returned by the lambda and the filter functions, I am storing the result in a list and printing the final output.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution and explanation for your question. Please view the image at the bottom of this answer for further clarification and to view the output.

```
lst = [['a', 'e'], ['g', 'j'], ['m', 'n', 'w'], ['z']] #So this is your list
character=input("Enter the character: ") #The character you are searching for
for a in lst: #it means that variable [a] is an item in the list [lst]
    for b in a: #it means that variable [b] is an item in the list [a]
        if(b==character): #To check if the given character is present in the list
             print(a) #Finally to print the list in which the given character is present
```

So, the code part is over. Now, let's look what the output will be.

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\python>coc.py

Enter the character: a
['a', 'e']

C:\Users\User\Desktop\python>coc.py

Enter the character: w
['m', 'n', 'w']
```

[Click here to view the image of my code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhM9w.png)