# Getting False value while checking if an input is present in a database where in fact it is present

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm not quite sure how to deal with this but i'm getting False values while comparing my input to the data present in the database. Here is my current code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('db_employees.db')
c = conn.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM tb_emp_info"
c.execute(query)
result = c.fetchall()
in_ = 'Permanent', # 'Permanent' is present in the database
print(in_ in result) # check if input is present in the database
```

Comment: Too many unknowns here.  Please post sample data for your table, and then explain what you are trying to check.

Comment: What does `print(result)` display?

Comment: Here is some of the data present in the table 'tb_emp_info': [('Permanent','Job Order','Contract of Service','Casual','Temporary')]. So 'Permanent' is in the table therefore my program should print True because 'Permanent' is in the 'result' but it prints False instead

Comment: BTW, I just noticed you have a `,` at the end of `in_ = 'Permanent',`, which is not going to work well - please delete it if it exists and [edit] the post.

Comment: I can't help but wonder why one would chek if `input` is present in the database _outside_ the database. Why not use a where clause to restrict the result to records that have that desired input as a value in a specific column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`fetchall()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html) returns a tuple for each row (note the link is for MySQL, but the explanation is better than the official docs):

> The method fetches all (or all remaining) rows of a query result set and returns a **list of tuples**. If no more rows are available, it returns an empty list.

This means `result` will look like:

```
[(field1, field2, f3...), (field1, field2, f3...), ...]
```

Now, `in` will check to see if any `(field1, field2, f3...)` equals `Permanent`, which is obviously always going to be false.

According [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2191699/1270789):

```
print(len([item for item in result if in_ in item]) > 0)
```

Or with @shmee's suggestion:

```
print(any(item for item in result if in_ in item))
```

This should print `True` if `in_` appears anywhere in `result`.

Comment: @Sev If that literally prints nothing, then I expect some issue with how you put that print statement into your programm. I see no reasonable way how this could not print either `True` or `False` in this context. However, I personally find that solution a bit clumsy. I'd go for sth. along the lines of `print(any(in_ in item for item in result))`.