# Re.search in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
L = [('revenue', 'IN'), ('units','IN'), ('between', 'IN')]
```

I what to search whether between exist in the list, If so, then i want to do some other operation.

i tried using

```
re.search("between", L, re.I)
```

but it is throwing error.

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Welcome! Which error? Please be more specific so volunteers on this site can actually understand what you are doing exactly and what exactly the error is. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find an element in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191699/find-an-element-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 1):

It will involve a simple iteration on the list.

```
for element in L:
   if L[0] == 'between':
            # do something
```

Why use a sword, when needle works fine for you?

Comment: Thanks @taurus05, Guessed it, it would be much simpler.

Comment: "operator_language_config": {
    "greater": ">",
    "lesser": "<",
    "equal": "=",
    "greater equal": ">=",
    "lesser equal": "<=",
    "between": "<>"
  }   i want to replace the between key to its value

Comment: This is a separate problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i in range(len(L)):
        for key, value in nlp_config['operator'].items():
            if L[i][0] == key:
                L[i] = (value,'IN')
```

I figured out the answer since L has tuple we need  to add its pair, to make it work.