# how to get specific element in a tuple based on condition

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

Trying to get specific element from a list contains tuples.

```
tuple_list= [('D:/test/1_birds_bp.png','D:/test/1_eagle_mp.png'), ('D:/test/2_crocodile_mp.png','D:/test/2_reptiles_bp.png')]
```

I want to  get elements that contains `bp`

So the expected output

`'D:/test/1_birds_bp.png'` in the first tuple group and `'D:/test/2_reptiles_bp.png'` from the second one

I tried

```
def get_tuple(tuple_list):

    for a in tuple_list:
        #if (any('bp' in i for i in a)): 
        #bp = [ x for x in a if 'bp' in x ]
        if 'bp' in a:    
            print(a)
        return a
print(get_tuple(tuple_list))
```

which gives me

```
('D:/test/1_birds_bp.png', 'D:/test/1_eagle_mp.png')
```

how can loop through in tuples and get the elements that meets the condition?

the expected output

'D:/test/1_birds_bp.png'

'D:/test/2_reptiles_bp.png'

I need to able to access them in a for loop fashion.

[Find an element in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191699/find-an-element-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: `result = [i for x in tuple_list for i in x if "bp" in i]`

Comment: Are the tuples in the list always of length 2?

Comment: @chatax yes! but the location might change

Comment: @jordanm I need to access an element from that list! which contains `bp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_tuple(tuple_list): 
   matches = []
   for t in tuple_list: 
       return tuple([a for a in t if 'bp' in a])

print(get_tuple(tuple_list))
```

Comment: thanks for solution. Actually what I need is how to access that element that contains `bp` I need to get that element!

Comment: So what does your expected output look like?

Comment: Is there a posibility that both elements contain 'bp'?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Let me know if this is what you want