# How to find a movie name in a list, which there was a part of 2 of the movie?

Tags: python

There is an array of movies, with tuples in it:

```
films = [(film_name,film_rating),...]
```

How do I find a film name which has the same name, but the number 2 added to it (like a part 2)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find an element in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191699/find-an-element-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: Yes this answers my question also. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider utilizing [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
>>> films = [('Kill Bill: Vol. 1', 8.2), ('Pulp Fiction', 8.9), ('Kill Bill: Vol. 2', 8.0)]
>>> kill_bill_films = [(film, rating) for (film, rating) in films if film.startswith('Kill Bill')]
>>> kill_bill_films
[('Kill Bill: Vol. 1', 8.2), ('Kill Bill: Vol. 2', 8.0)]
```

Or [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
>>> films_that_end_with_2 = [(film, rating) for (film, rating) in films if film.endswith('2')]
>>> films_that_end_with_2
[('Kill Bill: Vol. 2', 8.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You give very little information but if you want a movie that contains "part 2" in it's name, then the below code should be fine:

```
films = [("start wars 1",9.0 ), ("star wars part 2",10.0 )]
filmSet = []
for tple in films:
    if "part 2" in tple[0]:
        filmSet.append(tple)
print(filmSet)
```